# How do I play an audio file and display an image at the same time using an applet?

Tags: java, image, swing, audio, applet

This program can show and image with a call to the main and it can play an audio file when the applet is ran. Is there a way to do both of these at the same time?

```
public class DisplayWinner extends JApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
    int temp = (int)(Math.random()*2);
    String i1 ="0.png";
    String i2 ="1.jpg";

    images.add(i1);
    images.add(i2);

    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(images.get(temp)));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

    frame.add(label);  
    frame.setExtendedState( frame.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void init(){
    AudioClip ac = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "39602-    John_Cena_(ShortMp3.com).wav");
    ac.play();
}
}
```

Comment: You can add your JLabel to the applet.  But applets are not allowed to read files;  you’ll need to read the image as a [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) instead.

Comment: it is incorrect to say that applets cannot read files

Comment: An applet would not typically have a `main(String[])` method and when launched as an applet, the `main` will not be called. Move that code into the `init()` method (or another method that it calls).

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have in the init method:

```
public void init() { 

    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
    int temp = (int)(Math.random()*2);
    String i1 ="bm-0.png";
    String i2 ="bm-1.jpg";

    images.add(i1);
    images.add(i2);

    img=getImage(getDocumentBase(), "./"+images.get(temp));

    mt=new MediaTracker(this);

    mt.addImage(img, 0);

    try{
      mt.waitForID(0);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    try {
      AudioClip ac = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "e-20.wav");
      ac.play();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

and in the paint method

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) {    
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
  }
```